# How can I show who my bot is DMing and cannot DM. (discord.py)

Tags: python, logging, discord, discord.py, message

I understand the question is not phrased correctly or may not make any sense, so I will give a little context and information as to what I am trying to do...

**Context**

I am trying to create a bot that DMs everyone in my server to remind them of such and such, I have mastered the code on how to do this but I am having troubles figuring out how to make it show, who the bot is DMing and who it is not DMing.
I have researched for quite a bit and haven't found a solution which lead me here.

**Question**
How can I show who my bot is DMing and cannot DM. (The bot does do what it is supposed to do, DM everyone in the server upon request but I want it to be shown via terminal/pycharm/IDE.

Ex: User#1000 has successfully messaged User#2000!

```
import discord
import os, time, random
from discord.ext import commands
from lol import token
client = discord.Client()

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents, self_bot = True)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready!")
    
@client.command()
async def dm_all(ctx, *, args=None):
    if args != None:
        members = ctx.guild.members
        for member in members:
            try:
                await member.send(args)
                await print(ctx.discriminator.author)
            except:
                print("Unable to DM user because the user has DMs off or this is a bot account!")
    else: 
        await ctx.send("Please provide a valid message.")


client.run(token, bot=True)
```

Comment: What is it outputting now?

Comment: When it messages someone, it doesn't say anything and when it cant DM it just gives the except message; "Unable to DM user because the user has DMs off or this is a bot account!". I'm aware of the await print line, I was messing around with stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Here are some important things to know:***

1. If a user cannot receive a DM, then you get an `Forbidden` error.
2. You can use `except` statements to log these errors and display them in the console.
3. Most of the time you can't send direct messages to bots, then you get an `HTTPException` error.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@client.command()
async def dm_all(ctx, *, args=None):
    if args is not None:
        members = ctx.guild.members
        for member in members:
            try:
                await member.send(args)
                print(f"Sent a DM to {member.name}")
            except discord.errors.Forbidden:
                print(f"Could not send a DM to: {member.name}")
            except discord.errors.HTTPException:
                print(f"Could not send a DM to: {member.name}")

    else:
        await ctx.send("Please provide a valid message.")
```

**Output:**

```py
Sent a DM to Dominik
Could not send a DM to: BotNameHere
```

- Of course you can customize `member.name` according to your wishes.

**Reference:**
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=forbidden#discord.Forbidden